# How to use control M Parameter in Power BI desktop when executing a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, powerbi, m

I'm currently working on a Power BI report where I need to execute a stored procedure called `[RPT].[USP_RPT_P_VOID]` with a parameter `@START_DATE_SP` that I want to control dynamically from within the Power BI report.

However, I'm facing a dilemma: if I load the stored procedure in import mode, I can't directly bind the `@START_DATE_SP` parameter to any controls in the report, as import mode doesn't support bind to parameter.

On the other hand, if I load the stored procedure in direct query mode, I lose the ability to execute `exec [RPT].[USP_RPT_P_VOID]` directly because Power BI report doesn't support direct query load for exec statements.

Does anyone have any suggestions or workarounds for how I can dynamically control the `@START_DATE_SP` parameter while still being able to execute the stored procedure and load its results into my Power BI report?

Thank you for your help!